# Set responsive flexbox with column

Tags: html, css

Very often use flex-box because of handy design. But the problem is when I want to use two-column for mobile responsive design it takes me stuck. I use four-column in a row for large screens. It will show me two-column whenever the size of the screen `<768px`(mobile screens).

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}


@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .row {
    display: flex;
  }
  .col {
    flex-grow: 2;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h2>Column One</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h2>Column Two</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h2>Column Three</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h2>Column Four</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Expected Result**

[image]

I got stuck to make the two-column design. It always put me in one column for responsive screens. Have any way to make it two-column with minimalist css code?

Comment: The rule for `.col` is not going to apply because the only class on the `div`s is `col-3`. Are you using something like Bootstrap?

Comment: No, I just put the context like per column will row/4

Comment: By default, a `div` will take up 100% of the width of its container, so that's why it's a single column. I would do some research into the various properties that can be applied to `flex` elements; I've found [CSS-Trick's A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) to be a good reference for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `flex-wrap` and `flex-basis` based on the resolution:

<sub>Please see notes in the CSS</sub>

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

/* Basis to 49% so we get 2 cols per row */
.col {
  flex-basis: 49%;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

/* Enable wrap */
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
 
@media(min-width: 768px) {
  
  /* Disable wrap */
  .row {
    flex-wrap: nowrap ;
  }
  
  /* Basis to 20% so we get 4 col per row (+ padding) */
  .col {
    flex-basis: 20%;
  }  
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-3 col">
    <h2>Column One</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col">
    <h2>Column Two</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col">
    <h2>Column Three</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col-3 col">
    <h2>Column Four</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Small screen:
[image]

Large screen:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use media-query or bootstrap

```css
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.col {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .col {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h2>Column One</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h2>Column Two</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h2>Column Three</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h2>Column Four</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```